# sizeof a pointer

Tags: c++, sizeof

```
int i=0;
int *p = &i;
std::cout<<sizeof(i)<<" vs "<<sizeof(p)<<"\n";

char c='0';
char*pc = &c;
std::cout<<sizeof(c)<<" vs "<<sizeof(pc)<<"\n";

double d=0.123456789;
double *pd = &d;
std::cout<<sizeof(d)<<" vs "<<sizeof(pd)<<"\n";
```

Why is the size of a pointer always equal to that of an integer which is 4?

Comment: Try it on 64-bit and you will find that it is different. :)

Comment: It's a weird question; do you know what a pointer is? Why would you expect it to ever be differently sized?

Comment: C++ community is just huge, only with a simple question but I receive many replies in a little while. Glad! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that is how much memory a pointer takes:  4 bytes.

If this was a 64-bit application, it would return 8.

Answer (score 6):

Pointers don't *contain* the data they point to.

Pointers just *point to* the data they point to.

`sizeof( double* )` is the size of the data used to describe where a `double` is located.  Much as a piece of paper with a house address on it doesn't change size if the house is bigger or smaller, the size of a pointer is not a function of the size of the data pointed to.

Well, usually.  You could imagine international addresses being longer, and requiring more paper.  Similarly, you could imagine addresses inside an apartment building requiring an extra line for "unit number" compared to addresses elsewhere, or even "in-apartment" addresses that *only* contain the "unit number" and are thus shorter.  The standard allows the size of pointers to various types to vary, and some architectures (8086 most famously) has the concept of both near and far pointers (being 16 and 32 bits respectively).

This isn't common anymore (except maybe with member function pointers, but how common are those?)

Comment: Love the addressing examples you mentioned!

Answer (score 2):

<del>A pointer is actually a variable containing an address. On a 32-bit machine, the address is always 32-bit, so it's 4 bytes. The same logic for 16-bit or 64-bit machines.</del>

Just looked into the C99 standard and it says:

> The size of a pointer is not necessarily the same as the size of any
>   integer type. An implementation may support more than one size of
>   pointer.

Well, thus I think the safest way to know a pointer's size is `sizeof()`.

Comment: It might not contain an address. For instance, on some architectures it would contain a segment offset.

Comment: well, thanks for pointing out that, are you mentioning far pointers?

Comment: On some architectures there might be a concept of near/far pointers, yes. But that's not what the standard discusses. The standard places requirements on pointers which force them to operate in a memory-address-like fashion. But by no means does it require any relationship between the value stored in the pointer and physical storage locations on the target machine.

Answer (score 1):

A pointer will have a size depending on the kind of application you're compiling.

A pointer is like a `32-bit unsigned int` in a 32-bit application because it stores a memory location.

If the application is an `N-bit` application, the size of any pointer will be `N bits` long because it needs to be large enough to store the memory location.

Any `N-bit` computer that can run `N-bit` applications will have a RAM limit of `2^N bytes`. This makes the largest memory location id equal to `2^N - 1` (because `0x00000000` is a valid memory address).

`2^N - 1` requires `N bits` to be represented in binary, and that my friend is why a pointer has a size of 4 bytes in a 32-bit application.

Take a `3-bit` application for simplicity as an example: (I'd rather not deal with large numbers)

Let's assume it's running on a `3-bit` machine. Since `2^3 - 1` is the greatest number that can be represented in binary with `3 bits`, then the max memory that the system could handle would be `2^3` bytes. (These are unsigned. Negative memory addresses don't exist)

The possible memory addresses would be:

- `0x0` (Binary representation: `000`)
- `0x1` (Binary representation: `001`)
- `0x2` (Binary representation: `010`)
- `0x3` (Binary representation: `011`)
- `0x4` (Binary representation: `100`)
- `0x5` (Binary representation: `101`)
- `0x6` (Binary representation: `110`)
- `0x7` (Binary representation: `111`)

Thus, a pointer pointing to a memory address would need to have `3 bits` in such a case.

Replace `3` with `32` and this would apply to what you're doing here.

(Overkill answer much? Yes. Why? Because I was bored.)

Comment: Not always true. But true most of the time. Certainly not standards-mandated. For instance, it could contain a segment offset on some architectures, which might be smaller than the address space of the physical machine.

Comment: Of course, but I don't think anyone would fancy dealing with such special cases :p (Good thing no /sane/ programmer has to)

Comment: True, nobody wants to deal with special cases. But special cases are necessary for correct understanding in some cases. C and C++ place requirements on pointers which force them to be "address-like" -- but doesn't mandate any relationship between the data a pointer stores and the physical memory addressing model of the underlying machine,.