# Unexpected behavior of memset in C++

Tags: c++, c++17, memset

I have noticed unexpected behavior of `memset()` when used with dynamic arrays.

```
// This works well, sets value of each index = 0

int dp[5];
memset(dp, 0, sizeof(dp));


// This one doesn't work as expected, there are garbage values at some indexes

int *dp = new int[5];
memset(dp, 0, sizeof(dp));


// And this one works as expected

int *dp = new int[5];
memset(dp, 0, sizeof(dp[0]) * n);
```

What defines the reason for this unexpected behavior?

---

**EDIT**:

I understand that `sizeof(dp)` gives the size of pointer where as `sizeof(dp[0])` gives the size of `dp[0]`. My main concern is if first one is working fine with the pointer size i.e. `sizeof(dp)` then why isn't the second one working similarly, why are there garbage values?

Comment: In `int *dp = new int[5];` `dp` is a pointer. The size of a pointer is usually not the same as the size of the object pointed at.

Comment: `dp` is an `int*`. `sizeof(dp)` is probably 8 on your system, regardless of how many values are in the array `dp` points to the beginning of or what type those values are.

Comment: `sizeof(dp)` is the size of a pointer in your second example. Arrays are not pointers and pointers are not arrays

Comment: `sizeof(dp)` gives you the size of the object `dp`. If `dp` is a pointer it gives you the size of a pointer (NOTE: **NOT** what is pointed at). If `dp` is an array it gives you the size of the array. The problem is that because arrays will decay into pointers very easily, this leads a lot of people to think they have some equivalence, but this is not true they are very distinct types.

Comment: Why are you still using `memset`? In current C++ your code should be replaced by `std::vector<int> dp(5,0)`; which will result in a dynamically allocated array of 5 ints with value 0; memset is still available for backward compatibility, look at [`std::fill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) for replacing memset, `std::copy` (memcpy replacement that can even be faster) etc. for your future C++ code.

Comment: A side note about `memset`: It sets bytes.  In the working examples, every byte in the array at `dp` will be set to zero. Since `int` 0 will consist of all of the bytes in the `int` being 0, you get an array of `int`s all set to zero. But if you `memset` to 1, every byte is set to 1. With a 32 bit `int` that'll look like 0x01010101 or 16,843,009. In general, [prefer `std::fill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill).

Comment: @PepijnKramer I'm just curious.

Comment: In response to your edit: In the first one, `dp` is not a pointer. It is an array. `sizeof(dp)` is giving the size of an `int[5]` array. In the second and third ones, `dp` is a pointer.

Comment: As an aside, you can just initialize arrays to be empty, like `int dp[5] {};` and `int *dp = new int[5] {};`. No need to get garbage first, and then clear it (using old C functions).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sizeof a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15538210/sizeof-a-pointer)

Comment: "if first one is working fine with the pointer size i.e. `sizeof(dp)`..." That's your mistake: In the first example, `dp` is not a pointer.

Comment: @JanSchultke It all has come down to pointers but I still think that is not relevant.

Comment: @Cashflow Being curious is good. My comment is also for other readers that might have a similar question as you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
int dp[5];
```

declares `dp` as an array of 5 integers, a `int[5]`. Here `dp` is **not** a pointer. It is an array. Arrays are not pointers. The `sizeof dp` is `5 * sizeof int`.

---

On the other hand, this:

```
int* dp = ... whatever ...;
```

declares `dp` as a pointer to `int`, a `int*`. The `sizeof dp` is that of a `int*`.

Important: Pointers are not arrays and arrays are not pointers. The `dp` here is very different to the `dp` above. Here `dp` is a pointer to a single `int`, the first element of the dynamically allocated array.

---

When `dp` is a pointer, then `dp[0]` is equivalent to `*(dp + 0)`, hence `5 * sizeof dp[0]` is the total size of the array when `dp` points to the first element of an array with `5` integers.

---

Consider this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << sizeof(int) << "\n";
    std::cout << sizeof(int*) << "\n";
    std::cout << sizeof(int[5]) << "\n";
}
```

[Possible output is](https://godbolt.org/z/ehKKanx4e):

```
4
8
20
```

Here the size of a integer is 4 while the size of a pointer to integer is 8. Those numbers can differ, but the size of an array of 5 integers is always `5 * sizeof(int)` and typically `sizeof(int*)` is much smaller than `sizeof(int[5])`.

---

About your edit...

> My main concern is if first one is working fine with the pointer size i.e. sizeof(dp) then why isn't the second one working similarly, why are there garbage values?

See above. In the first example `dp` is **not** a pointer. When you declare `dp` as `int dp[5];` then `dp` is **not** a pointer. It is an array. Arrays are not pointers. `int* dp = ...` on the other hand declares `dp` as a pointer to integer.

---

PS: Use a vector instead of manually managed c-arrays and skip the usage of `memset`:

```
std::vector<int> x(5);
std::cout << "number of elements: " << x.size();
```

Comment: I understand why third one is working perfectly fine as expected now. But if first one is working fine as well then why is second one still having garbage values?

Comment: @Cashflow because `sizeof(int*)` is smaller than `sizeof(int[5])`.

Comment: @Cashflow not sure how to explain better. If the third one is perfectly fine then the second cannot be right

Comment: That's true, no doubt. But why `sizeof(int*)`  is working fine for the first one then?

Comment: @Cashflow please read the answer carefully. `int dp[5];` declares `dp` as an array of 5 integers. It is not a pointer. It is an array

Comment: @Cashflow It's easy to confuse an array for a pointer because it in many cases is implicitly converted to a pointer. Not in `sizeof` though.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number OMG thank you so much, straight to the point. I really thought dp is a pointer in the first one as well. It is a little confusing as usually it is a pointer. Thanks again!

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes, it helped. I appreciate your response. I confused it for a pointer.